# Событие .on('click', 'body *' вызывается для каждого родительского элемента

Tags: jquery

Например, есть страница

```js
$(document).on('click', 'body *', function() {
  console.log($(this));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>

<body>
  <div class="a1">
    <div class="a2">
      <div class="a3">
        <div class="a4">
          <div class="a5">
            test
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Так вот, проблема в том, что нажав на div.a5, вызовется событие, после этого событие будет вызываться и к каждому родителю: a4, a3, a2, a1

Как сделать так, чтобы не вызывалось событие у родительских элементов?

P.S. Содержимое страницы изменяется динамически, поэтому и используется .on

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нашел решение

```
event.stopPropagation();
```

Данный метод предотвращает вызов события у родительских элементов

Вот ответ:

```
$(document).on('click', 'body *', function(event) {
  console.log($(this));
  event.stopPropagation();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Может проще сделать уточнение?

```
$(document).on('click', 'body .a5', function()
{
    console.log($(this));
});
```

Comment: Оно не подойдет, я не написал для чего я это использую..
Я пишу дополнение к браузеру. При нажатии на кнопку, появляется блок, чтобы его закрыть нужно нажать на что-то другое.
То есть я обрабатываю все события клика и если не нахожу в родительских элементах нужный - скрываю блок.
А в данном случае, у первых элементов будет нужный родитель, у остальных нет. И получается, что в любом случае блок будет скрыт, на что бы не нажали..

Comment: @СтаниславГрот, так вы тогда напишите HTML-код, который будет учитывать все тонкости логики, потому что в данной реализации до внутреннего блока можно достучаться разными способами, но эти способы не будут учитывать то, что структура элементов может быть другая